# React native components cannot be used as a JSX components after installing @types/styled-components-react-native

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to develop an application using react native expo bare worflow with typescript and styled components.

I was able to install styled components with yarn add styled-components and then yarn add @types/styled-components-react-native.

After this I was also able to create my styled components, but in the moment that I install @types/styled-components-react-native suddenly all my JSX components like View, Text, TouchableHighlight, etc, start giving me the message (ts2786):

View cannot be used as a JSX components

Text cannot be used as a JSX components

TouchableHighlight cannot be used as a JSX components ........

The application is running normally, but still this error is bothering me...

I tried not to install the styled components types, but the hot reload stops to work.

All my packages and react native is updated.

Thanks.

[JSX error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3AX0.png)

Comment: Can you add some reproducible code?
What are the extensions of your files?

Comment: Can you add you tsconfig.json as well?

Comment: @JSharles This is my tsconfig.json { "compilerOptions": { "strict": true }, "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base" }

Comment: @LeviD. To reproduce the problem you just create an expo app with bare work flow, add typescript on it and then install styled components and styled components type. The extensions I'm using is .tsx

Comment: Do you use VSCode? It might be the intellisense TS version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a long day I discovered that when I was installing styled components types with @types/styled-components-react-native it was updating my react and react-dom to version 18 in package.json and this is what was giving me the error, since react-native in based in react version 17

To fix it just change versions to :

dependencies:
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2"

devDependencies:
"@types/react": "~17.0.21"